# Error when importing module in main Python installation: module is called from an inexistent venv Python

Tags: python, macos, pandas, virtualenv, geopandas

I am working in an IPython interpreter started from the terminal (MacOSX) with just an `ipython` + `enter`. When I try to import `pandas`, I get the following error:

```
/Users/myusername/Documents/somefolder/virtualenvironment/adam_py/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py in <module>()
  4 
  5 try:
  ----> 6     from . import hashtable, tslib, lib
  7 except Exception:  # pragma: no cover
  8     import sys

/Users/myusername/tslib.pyx in init pandas.tslib (pandas/tslib.c:64182)()

ImportError: No module named compat
```

The first line of that error suggests that python is looking for pandas in a venv in a folder I deleted some time ago.
I get a similar error when I try to import geopandas.

My Python installation is a homebrewed one. When I run `which python` in the terminal, I get this:

```
/usr/local/bin/python
```

I have been installing libraries with `pip install a_library`

What should I do?

Comment: What version of pandas do you have installed?

Comment: I did a `pip show pandas | grep Version`. It says it is version 0.15.1

Comment: Why is this link to a former virtualenvironment popping out in the error message if I am running an interpreter of the main homebrewed Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just deleted the folder containing the former virtual environment, closed the interpreter, pip-uninstalled pandas, pip-installed it again, and reopened the interpreter. Now I can import pandas without problems.